# How to delete all php files first line?

Tags: linux, centos, php

How to delete all php files first line? I used the following command, but it works only for present directory and not recursively.

`sed 1d file.php`

Please tell me the command or script which delete all files first line recursively.

Comment: This will **not** help you recover from a compromise.

Answer (score 1):

Probably better explain us what you **really** have in mind.

The command would be (from the top directory) :

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed 1d -i '{}' \;
```

Comment: Ok.Thanks.If i run the command it shows the following error. "find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter"

Comment: It is `-type f` Was a typo i guess...

Comment: error : "find: unknown predicate `-f'". Pleaase suggest the right command

Comment: Yes, typo. Corrected.